# call "deleting" function with cascadeOnDelete()

Tags: php, cascade, laravel-9

I am developing an app in which you can create events and add posts to them. I have two Tables called `events` and `posts`. The events table has a `preview_image` column. The posts table has a `picture` column and a foreignId `event_id`.

```php
Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('id');
    // ...
    $table->string('preview_image')->nullable();
    // ...
});
```

```php
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('id');
    // ...
    $table->string('picture');
    $table->foreignId('event_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    // ...
});
```

An example for an entry in both colums looks like this

Post

```
picture: "posts/2Ddh4wiTrBGBWQkRhQbTUTFGdVCFoW3KzvIhpfKW.png"
```

Event

```
preview_image: "events/lOzjzjSZul4tGULxzxfIxzfJGBlohe9np6NLazjA.jpg"
```

In my `Event` model I am overwriting the boot method to create a `deleting` function to delete the `preview_image`

```php
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($event) {
        $picture = $event->preview_image;
        if ($picture) {
            $picturePath = storage_path('app/public/' . $picture);
            if (file_exists($picturePath)) {
                unlink($picturePath);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I delete an Event all relating posts and the preview_image gets deleted.
Now I want the `picture` of every post to be deleted when the Post is deleted. So I did the same thing to my Post model.

```php
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function ($post) {
        $picture = $post->picture;
        if ($picture) {
            $picturePath = storage_path('app/public/' . $picture);
            if (file_exists($picturePath)) {
                unlink($picturePath);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My file structure:

```
app
 public
   events
      event1.png
   posts
      post1.png
```

This is the function I am calling to delete the Event

```php
public function deleteEvent($id)
{
    $event = Event::findOrFail($id);
    $event->delete();
    return response()->json($event);
}
```

For some reason the picture of the post does not get deleted.

Does the `deleting` function not get called if the posts are removed by `cascadeOnDelete()`? If so how can I call the deleting function while deleting each post. Or is there another method to delete relating files with `cascadeOnDelete()`.

laravel version: v9.24.0

Comment: If you're deleting the database entry before you're deleting the filepath then the file delete methods will not have the database values to work from (the image filepaths). You need to delete the filepath because it's referenced in the database, before then deleting the table entry(s).

Comment: @martin I thought the the `deleting` method gets called as soon as the `post` gets deleted. Is this this not the case if it gets deleted by `cascadeOnDelete`?!

Comment: @Martin does the deleting method get called after the entry is deleted? If so why does it work perfectly with the Event entry?

Comment: Your `picture` image deletion static method needs to be called **before** your event deletion static method.

Comment: @Martin how do I do that if the post is deleted by cascadeOnDelete() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cascading delete happens at the database level. There are no Eloquent events fired.

If you need Eloquent events to fire on the deleted child records, you'll need to ditch `cascadeOnDelete`, and implement the deletion cascade yourself via a `deleted` event on the parent model.

Answer (score 0):

cascading delete does not execute the `deleting` function in my `Post` model.
Like [ceejayoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902010/ceejayoz) said:

> A cascading delete happens at the database level. There are no
> Eloquent events fired.

I solved this problem by calling the delete function of each post before deleting the event.

```php
public function deleteEvent($id)
{
    $event = Event::findOrFail($id);
    $posts = $event->posts;
    foreach ($posts as $post){
        $post->delete();
    }
    $event->delete();
    return response()->json($event);
}
```

now `cascadeOnDelete` is unnecessary and I can remove it